# rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use select query for retrieving data from table. I have found, `rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)` method of `SQLiteDatabase` class to retrieve data. But I don't know how the `query` and `selectionArgs` should be passed to `rawQuery` method?

Comment: [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)Android developer is the best source for all these small queries is the best source for all these small queries

Answer (score 234, accepted):

```
rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name = ? AND id = ?", new String[] {"David", "2"});
```

You pass a string array with an equal number of elements as you have "?"

Comment: `rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE ?= ?", new String[] {"column_name", "David"});`, is this a validQuery?

Comment: @theapache64 it is not a valid query. The '?' is only applicable to values.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe this can help you

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("query",null);
int id[] = new int[c.getCount()];
int i = 0;
if (c.getCount() > 0) 
{               
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        id[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("field_name"));
        i++;
    } while (c.moveToNext());
    c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

One example of rawQuery - `db.rawQuery("select * from table where column = ?",new String[]{"data"});`

Comment: What is new String[]{"data"}? Can you just give an explanation of above statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29

Answer (score 6):

if your SQL query is this

```
SELECT id,name,roll FROM student WHERE name='Amit' AND roll='7'
```

then rawQuery will be

```
String query="SELECT id, name, roll FROM student WHERE name = ? AND roll = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"Amit","7"} 
db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```

Answer (score 2):

see below code it may help you.

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM customer";
Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(q, null);
```

or

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE _id = " + customerDbId  ;
Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(q, null);
```

Comment: Why is this up-voted? This does not show how to properly use the functionality provided by `rawQuery`. Its purpose is to avoid concatenating Strings, etc.
Also, Rawkode's answer should be accepted.

Comment: This is not how rawQuery should be used, you should be using ? as placeholders and the second parameter to fill them in.

Comment: Regardless "how" you're supposed to use *rawQuery()*, THIS is the more sensible, short, comprehensible and standard way in all other languages, apart Java. So this is way preferred.

Comment: @aMiGo The string is concatenated anyway the layer below.

Comment: If you concatenate a string value, you get problems with the character ' (need 2 of them in the string) and the character ; (might create side effects). Suppose CustomerDbId is a string that reads  --  '123'; delete from customer    -- then you would loose ALL data!

Comment: it is ashaming that this is upvoted by 3 people. this is how you end up with sql injections or errors

Answer (score 2):

For completeness and correct resource management:

```
        ICursor cursor = null;
        try
        {

            cursor = db.RawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + RECORDS_TABLE + " WHERE " + RECORD_ID + "=?", new String[] { id + "" });

            if (cursor.Count > 0)
            {
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
            }
            return GetRecordFromCursor(cursor); // Copy cursor props to custom obj
        }
        finally // IMPORTANT !!! Ensure cursor is not left hanging around ...
        {
            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String mQuery = "SELECT Name,Family From tblName";
Cursor mCur = db.rawQuery(mQuery, new String[]{});
mCur.moveToFirst();
while ( !mCur.isAfterLast()) {
        String name= mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        String family= mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("Family"));
        mCur.moveToNext();
}
```

Name and family are your result