# Use variable in SQLite Query

Tags: android, sqlite

First of all I've looked up several topics on this but nothing specifically addressing this issue in Java.

I have the following method.

```
public String getCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String w = "Home";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE + 
            " where " + KEY_LOCATION + " = 'Home'", null);

    int i = cursor.getCount();
    String s = ("You have " + i + " entries in this column");

    return s;
}
```

I would like this `query` to use the variable  above it rather than a specific hard coded `String` "Home".

I've tried `+ {w}` `+ {w%}` `+ w` and a few others, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE + 
        " where " + KEY_LOCATION + " = '" + w + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to user the selectionArgs parameters that you set to null in your rawQuery method.

An example can be founde here [rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs)

Comment: For sure, otherwise its easy to attack my db. I just needed this part to work first. Now I'm on to that, thank you though