# Java Sql Select from Column where Month

Tags: java, sql

I'm having Day, Month and Year stored as Integers in my SQL DataBase. I checked so they are stored with the right number by printing them to a textfield.

I have this method where I  want to get all the data that is saved month number x
but It crashes. Could Someone point me in the right direction of how to retreive all the data that is saved to month number x.

Here is what I got

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Cursor getMonth(int month) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS WHERE MONTH = "
            + month, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

Here's the error code

```
10-09 19:01:27.942: E/AndroidRuntime(610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 19:01:27.942: E/AndroidRuntime(610): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
10-09 19:01:27.942: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at      
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery
com.waffles.vatsandbats.MyDBHandler.getMonth(MyDBHandler.java:85)
```

I have this code that gets all the rows and works fine

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String where = null;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate of "but it crashes"? What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Is it your intention to use table named "TABLE_PRODUCTS" in the first query, but use a reference to TABLE_PRODUCTS variable when constructing the second query? Can you please include the TABLE_PRODUCTS variable declaration in the question?

Comment: You might take a look a this question. Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try removing one of the parameters from your rawQuery call:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS WHERE MONTH = "
            + month, null);
```

Take a look at the docs:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Comment: 10-09 19:14:28.572: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 19:14:28.572: E/AndroidRuntime(639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.waffles.vatsandbats/com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaData}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_PRODUCTS: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS WHERE MONTH = 10

Comment: Now i get a different message

Comment: It seems that your TABLE_PRODUCTS doesn't exist. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

I took away one of the parameter and changed the query code a little bit and now it worked with this line of code

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE "
            + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + month + "\"", null);
```