# Is there a more robust way to make join queries in Android / Java / SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, join, parameters

I'm not sure which framework this is specific to but I think it's Android.

Normally you can use Cursors and ContentValues to do basic queries on tables, but with things like table joins you have to use raw queries as far as I can tell.

But if I am making raw queries than I have to go with the old string concatenation approach which I believe is considered bad practice because you can run into bugs and character-escape issues.

Is there a more robust way to perform join queries?

Comment: "But if I am making raw queries than I have to go with the old string concatenation approach" -- no. "Is there a more robust way to perform join queries?" -- the same way you do queries without joins: use positional parameters (`?` placeholders). What makes you think those are unusable for a SQL SELECT statement with one or more JOIN clauses?

Comment: @CommonsWare The way you do queries without joins is different than queries with joins

Comment: I don't have my code on my at the moment but it's something like `Cursor c = db.query(tableName, 
            tableColumn, 
            where, 
            whereArgs,
            groupBy,
            having,
            orderBy);` and then you can use the cursor to iterate over the results and map the contents to whatever objects you want. In contrast I believe joins can only be done using `db.rawQuery()` or however it's called.

Comment: "What makes you think those are unusable for a SQL SELECT statement with one or more JOIN clauses? " Because as far as I know, using " = ?" where ? is `someString` is the same as doing " = " + `someString`

Comment: You do not have to use `query()` to query a database. That is *a* way of querying a database. There are several in Android. You claim that `rawQuery()` requires string concatenation. It does not. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10598193/115145.

Comment: That is a different way only in the sense that it uses `String.format()` under the hood (I would guess) but it's functionally the same as doing a string concatenation all the same.

Comment: "Because as far as I know, using " = ?" where ? is someString is the same as doing " = " + someString" -- no, query parameters are more sophisticated than that. For example, SQLite handles escaping of quotation marks and such.

Comment: This stuff is open-source right? Is there a way to see how db.query / db.rawQuery is implemented? You say it is not the only way to do a query -- what are the other ways?

Comment: "Is there a way to see how db.query / db.rawQuery is implemented?" -- you are welcome to look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java). Eventually, you start hitting SQLite APIs. "what are the other ways?" -- `SQLiteQueryBuilder`, prepared statements, etc.

Comment: I thought this was a form of prepared statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never a need to use string concatenation; `rawQuery()` supports parameters, too. (Parameters are passed directly into the database, without having to format them.)

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM a JOIN b USING (id) WHERE name = ?",
                     new String[]{ name });
```