# select in SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How I can select two columns in SQLite database.I wrote this code but I was wrong code.can anyone helps me where is my mistake?

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TableUsers+" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.COL_UserName,DatabaseHelper.COL_Password+,new String[]{UserName, Password});
```

Comment: That code does not compile, please post your actual code and specify what problem you're having exactly. If it is an exception, post the full stacktrace.

Comment: That is aweful. Use Stored Procedures instead of patching things together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs)

Comment: sir, i have started to learn Android since NOV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I instantly want to open with the fact that this answer is based on the fact that you use the SQL terms correctly, and you know that `select two columns` means picking two columns from one (or more) row(s) returned from a query

---

You're using the `WHERE` clause wrong. It's intended to pick where a column has a given value. For an instance, if you have a table with an `INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY` and want to pick the row with `id = 10`, you do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=10`.

<sub>You should use stored procedures, so that converted to support that is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?` and pass a String[] array with the argument to fill on.</sub>

Now that you understand the actual basics of the `WHERE` clause, let me move on to your code.

You're using `,` and hence adding more arguments outside the String. Secondly, you can't have multiple passed arguments, the only thing supported is a String list and this is for avoiding SQL injection.

Now, for picking specific columns it's easier.

First off, you need `moveToFirst` to make sure the query isn't empty. Then `isAfterLast` is used to check if there are no more entries left. And then you just pick the applicable values you want. Example:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //These are just examples of values you can select from the returned row. Edit based on your database and the rows you want. `COLUMN_ID` and `COLUMN_STACKTRACE`
            //are Strings with the column name

            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
            String stack = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_STACKTRACE));
            //Here you'd add these to a List or something, maybe as a dataclass. Essentially, TODO: Handle your data here
            cursor.moveToNext();//Move to the next row
        }
    }
    cursor.close();//Close the cursor
}
```

---

Addition to the `WHERE` keyword explanation.

If you have a row where `id = 10, field1 = "11.12.17", field3 = "some data here"` and you want to select that row based on the ID, you'd use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=10` to select all the rows where the ID is 10. In some cases you'd get one row, in others you could get 1000.

Comment: I want to create a login form.after customers registered.go to another activity and sign in to the app . and I need two columns from my database UserName &&Password

Answer (score 1):

With raw query the code should be:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TableUsers+" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.COL_UserName+"='"+UserName+"' And "+DatabaseHelper.COL_Password+"='"+ Password+"'");
```

Even though I prefer using prepared statements.