# In an Android application and SQLite3 database, Is there any need to check if the updated data on the database is truly updated

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application and SQLite3 database,
Is there any need to check if the updated data on the database is truly updated or just successful transaction without any exception is enough?

In other words, in the following code, is there any need for rawQuery with ***POSTS_SELECT_QUERY*** or not ?

```
public boolean update_C_Data(String mID,String mData)
    {
        boolean Fault_Flg = true;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.clear();
            values.put(KEY_C_Data, mData);
            String[] mArgs = new String[]{mID};
            int rows = db.update(TABLE_C, values, KEY_C_ID +"= ?", mArgs);

            if (rows == 1)
            {
                String POSTS_SELECT_QUERY =
                        String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s AND %s = %s;",
                                TABLE_C,
                                KEY_C_ID,
                                "'"+mID+"'",
                                KEY_C_Data,
                                "'"+mData+"'"
                        );

                Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(POSTS_SELECT_QUERY, null);
                try
                {
                    if (mCursor.getCount() == 1)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Fault_Flg = false;
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed())
                    {
                        mCursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Fault_Flg = false;
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Fault_Flg = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        return Fault_Flg;
    }
```

Comment: Unless you're playing fast and loose with dangerous settings (Disabling the journal, turning off synchronous mode), as long as an insertion doesn't return an error, you can be very confident it succeeded (Not counting things like `INSERT OR IGNORE` with a constraint conflict, of course).

Comment: Sorry, would you please explain more?

Comment: It's an [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database.

Comment: So you mean there is no need to verify the updated data or you mean there is a need under certain circumstances?

Comment: @AndroidHV  Shawn posted very useful information for you to determine a final answer on your own.  If the Wikipedia link wasn't enough, then [read this statement](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) on the official sqlite website.  ACID transactions are meant to provide a high level of trust that the data is written successfully.

Comment: @AndroidHV   If the transaction fails, then an exception is thrown and the code should roll back the transaction.  This is done by NOT calling `setTransactionSuccessful()`.  Interestingly enough, it looks like your verification code is not correct anyway since it appears to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` regardless of the result of the SELECT query.  It is also a better practice to default a "success flag" (i.e. Fault_flg) to false and only set it to true upon success.  It also is named opposite of its use which seems awkward.  Wouldn't "fault = true" indicate an error?

Comment: @AndroidHV  It is also best to use SQL **parameters** rather than building the SQL string manually in the call to `rawQuery()`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598193/1261752) for an example.  Note that you will still have to insert column names separately, but the values should be passed as parameter arguments.

Comment: @AndroidHV  Also, if the `db.update()` returns 0 rows (so that `rows == 1` is false), is it correct that this really is a valid state without error?  I'm in doubt that that is correct since the other logic seems questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQLite is ACID, there is no need to verify the data after update
The code could be as following:

```
public boolean update_C_Data(String mID,String mData)
    {
        boolean Fault_Flg = true;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.clear();
            values.put(KEY_C_Data, mData);
            String[] mArgs = new String[]{mID};

            db.update(TABLE_C, values, KEY_C_ID +"= ?", mArgs);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Fault_Flg = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        return Fault_Flg;
    }
```