# Check null cursor crashes the program

Tags: kotlin, null, cursor

I've a serious problem checking cursor for nullity, The cursor loads some data from a table, if it returns null value it crashes, I tried several solutions like (if (c == null)), (if  (c == 0)), I even tried c.isBeforeFirst()

the function of the cursor is:

```
fun getArrayList1(dbHelper: DBHelper, type: Int): ArrayList<String> {
    var rv = ArrayList<String>()
    var query = ""
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    if (type == TYPE_DH) {
        query = "SELECT " + DBHelper.COL_45 + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_HOL + " WHERE (" + DBHelper.COL_43 + " LIKE '%" + sel2 + "%') AND (" + DBHelper.COL_44 + " LIKE '%" + sel3 + "%')"
        } else {
    }
    Log.d("GETARRAYLIST", "Query is \n\t" + query)
    val c: Cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)
    c.moveToFirst()
    if (c.isBeforeFirst()) {
        getnull(dbHelper)
    } else {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(c.getString(0))
            textView13.text = rv.toString()

            return rv
        }
    }
    c.close()
    return rv
}
```

Here i'm trying to check if the cursor returns null value then the program would execute another function:

```
fun getnull(dbHelper: DBHelper) : ArrayList<String> {
    var rv = ArrayList<String>()
    var query1 = ""
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    query1 = "SELECT " + DBHelper.COL_45 + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_HOL + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COL_43 + " LIKE '%" + sel2 + "%'"
    val c2 = db.rawQuery(query1, null)
    textView13.text = "0"
    showToast("هذا السيد / " + sel3 + " لم يحصل على أي أجازات سابقة")
    c2.close()
    return rv
}
```

In my program, I'm trying to save data of holidays taken by employees. In my page, I recall 2 columns (First is Employee Name, Second is number of holidays he taken). In the main function, select part of (+ DBHelper.COL_44 + " LIKE '%" + sel3 + "%'") I know that it'll return  null value, cause it will return a name of someone that didn't take a holiday yet.

so anyone can help me figure that problem out?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `cursor.Count`  as [@ComeIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs) suggested:

```
if (cursor.Count > 0) {
      cursor.MoveToFirst();
}
```

And close cursor on `finally`

```
finally  {
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.Close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it before, n tried it again with declaration of @ComeIn but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

> ```
> c.moveToFirst()
> if (c.isBeforeFirst()) {
>     getnull(dbHelper)
> } else {
>     while (c.moveToNext()) {
>         rv.add(c.getString(0))
>         textView13.text = rv.toString()
>
>         return rv
>     }
> }
> c.close()
> return rv
> ```

with something like

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       rv.add(c.getString(0))
   } while (c.moveToNext())
   textView13.text = rv.toString()
} else {
    rv = getnull(dbHelper)
}
c.close()
return rv
```

Because of:

- `moveToFirst()` always moves the row to the first one regardless if it exists or not. `isBeforeFirst()` returns thus false. You can examine the return value of `moveTo..()` to see if the cursor points to a valid row.
- `moveToFirst()` followed by `moveToNext()` would skip the first result row. Hence `do`-`while` to move the cursor after reading the row.
- Updating the same textview in each loop iteration is not needed, that can be done after the loop.
- You were not doing anything with the `getnull()` result
- It's better to `close()` the cursor in all branches of the code.