# what is the right way to write this simple sqlite rawquery?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using sqlite after a lot of years.
I am writing a simple query in sqlite but getting error.
I searched google, but they are showing advanced errors, none shows this simple error.
code:

```
**public Cursor getLastData(int data) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME, selectionArgs:"STATUS = 1");// error here near status = 1
        return res;
    }**
```

Also can I use SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work

```
public Cursor getLastData(int data) {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    
            String query = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE STATUS = 1";
    
            Cursor cursor = null ;
    
            try{
                cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
            }catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                Log.d("error",ex.toString());
            }
            return cursor ;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE STATUS = 1");
```