# How to check if an item is in a database before trying to add it

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that is adding to and updating a database. The student ID number is the primary key. I'm trying to have the app display a message when the user attempts to add a duplicate. This is my latest attempt; it's triggering the catch clause.

In my main activity, I have this conditional statement:

```
 if (!dbHandler.checkStudentID(studentID)){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Student ID is a Duplicate",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 dbHandler.addNewStudent(studentID, firstName, lastName, grade);
```

In my handler the method is this:

```
public boolean checkStudentID (String studentID) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor checkID = db.rawQuery("SELECT student_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                   " where student_id=?", new String[]{studentID});
   String x = checkID.getString(0);
   checkID.close();
   return x.isEmpty();
}
```

Logcat isn't showing any issues and there aren't any syntax problems shown, so I'm at a loss as to what's not correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android sqlite how to check if a record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415309/android-sqlite-how-to-check-if-a-record-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a Cursor **rawQuery** will return a Cursor that is positioned **before the first row** (as do any of the SQLiteDatabase methods that return a Cursor). To extract data you need to position the Cursor accordingly.

In your case all you need to know is whether or not any data was extracted, as such you can use the **[moveToFirst](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToFirst())** method. This will return true if the move could be made (if there is any data) or false (if there is no data).

So you could use something like :-

```
public static boolean checkStudentID (String studentID) {
   boolean rv = false;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor checkID = db.rawQuery("SELECT student_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                   " where student_id=?", new String[]{studentID});
   if (checkID.moveToFirst()) {
       rv = true;
   }
   checkID.close();
   return rv;
}
```

> This is my latest attempt; it's triggering the catch clause.

Because you are trying to access data when the Cursor is before the first row when you execute `String x = checkID.getString(0);`, hence an exception being caught/trapped.

Comment: That makes sense, and I've updated my code. I was able to iterate through the table and it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if the `studentID` could not be found, `String x = checkID.getString(0)` contains `null`. And with that, calling `x.isEmpty()` will throw a NullPointerException. So you should intercept that by:

```
public static boolean checkStudentID (String studentID) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor checkID = db.rawQuery("SELECT student_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                   " where student_id=?", new String[]{studentID});
   String x = checkID.getString(0);
   checkID.close();
   if (x == null || x.isEmpty()) {
       return false;
   }
   else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

I think you could even leave `x.isEmpty()` out altogether.

If the `Toast.makeText().show()` doesn't terminate the program, you should better wrap that `addNewStudent` part in an `else`-case. Otherwise, it will still be executed!

```
if (!dbHandler.checkStudentID(studentID)){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Student ID is a Duplicate",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
   dbHandler.addNewStudent(studentID, firstName, lastName, grade);
}
```

Comment: If I try your cursor query, I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'rawQuery(java.lang.String)'

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't know how rawQuery worked before, but your approach is technically correct according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598193/13701381 
Did you try to wrap the addNewStudent already?

Comment: @KillerSheltie I've changed my suggestion. Please have a look at it again!

Comment: I tried; it's still erroring out and hitting my catch clause instead of being handled.

Comment: How do you call the function for testing? With which student, example values in db etc.

Comment: I've a student already in the database: student ID is 007. So, I'm testing by trying to add another 007 student. Here's the whole thing if you want a look: https://github.com/NicoleWilbur/student_grades_system